# Add or remove item in datagrid does not trigger WhenAnyPropertyChanged

Tags: mvvm, datagrid, reactiveui

I am using dynamic data with reactiveui,

```
`  _propList.Connect()
        .WhenAnyPropertyChanged()
        .Subscribe(t =>
        {
        }`
```

the code will be trigger if I just edit any item in the grid.  However, when I try to add or remove an item, it is not triggered.

In my view model I have something like this

```
   private SourceList<Decision> _myList { get; set; } = new SourceList<Decision>();
        private readonly IObservableCollection<Decision> _targetCollection = new ObservableCollectionExtended<Decision>();
        public IObservableCollection<Decision> TargetCollection => _targetCollection;
```

in my view, I simply

```
        this.OneWayBind(VM, vm => vm.TargetCollection, v => v.DataGrid1.DataSource);
```

If I remove or Add item in the grid, and press Save

_myList.Count() didn't change, but
_TargetCollection.Count() will increase or decrease by number of items I delete

In my ViewModel

```
  OKCmd = ReactiveCommand.Create(() =>
        {
        ////    _myList.Connect()
        ////.Subscribe(t =>
        //// {
        ////     ;

        //// }
        //// );
```

t.Items.count() and it is the initial load items, but I couldn't seem to know what items have been added or removed.  Am I missing something.

Of course, I can keep track of what items are added or removed in the UI, but I am hoping I don't have to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To help me answer your question, I need to better understand what you are trying to achieve but first I will explain what the default behaviour of DD is.

1. If you want add / remove events you need  `_propList.Connect().Subscribe(changes => ...)`. These are the collection changes and you will receive all collection change events including the initial load, but no inline changes.
2. By default, no property changes are wire in. This is because to monitor property changes is expensive and is opt in only. Also `WhenAnyPropertyChanged()` never tiggers for the initial load. This is because the item is already loaded and no properties have changed between `Connect` being called and the property changed observable being subscribed to.
3. Following on from 2, you will never receive a property changed when an item is removed from the underlying source. This is because when an item it removed, any inline subscriptions are disposed of. Otherwise there would be memory leaks.
4. Another option for monitoring inline changes is to make use of 'MergeMany' which allows you to craft any observable on a specific item, and in your case you can create an observable to return the initial value as well as as subsequent changes.

It is possible using standard rx to listen to collection changes and inline changes in a single observable, which you would have to compose yourself. For example

```cs
var myCollectionChanges = _propList.Connect();
var myPropertyChanges = _propList.Connect().WhenAnyPropertyChanged();

var allMyChanges = myCollectionChanges.Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                     .Merge(myPropertyChanges.Select(_ => Unit.Default));
```

In the this example, I have used `Select(_ => Unit.Default)` to enable the merge operator as it requires the same signature. However what signature is returned is up to you, the key point being that the signatures must match.